# Reactjs map function mapping more elements than the ones present in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have an array of objects that is like this:

```
data = [{
            "projectId": 1,
            "projectName": "Progetto 1",
            "clientId": 1,
            "projectDescription": "description1",
            "projectMailingList": "mailingList1",
            "projectCreationDate": "apr 29, 2019",
            "projectVersion": 1
        },
        {
            "projectId": 2,
            "projectName": "Progetto 2",
            "clientId": 1,
            "projectDescription": "description2",
            "projectMailingList": "mailingList2",
            "projectCreationDate": "apr 29, 2019",
            "projectVersion": 1
        },
        {
            "projectId": 3,
            "projectName": "Progetto 3",
            "clientId": 1,
            "projectDescription": "description3",
            "projectMailingList": "mailingList3",
            "projectCreationDate": "apr 29, 2019",
            "projectVersion": 1
        }];
```

I use the map function for this array, but it's mapping more elements than the ones present. What I have to do is to render a custom component for each of the element of the array, so that would be 3 times, instead it's creating it 7 times. I've tried doing this inside constructor, to check:

```
this.data.map(projectId => console.log("Call "));
```

and it correctly prints "Call" for 3 times. Then, in my render method I do this:

```
return (
      <Slider class="mySlider" ref = {c => (this.slider = c)} {...this.settings}>
        {
          this.data.map(projectId => 
              <ProjectComponent key={projectId} project={projectId} time={this.state.timestamp} originalIndex={ i++ } currentIndex = {this.state.activeSlide}></ProjectComponent>)
        }
      </Slider>
    );
```

and it creates 7 `ProjectComponent` s. Why is that? And why 7?

**EDIT**
This is `ProjectComponent`:

```
export class ProjectComponent extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.logger = new LoggerService();
    this.state = {
      project: this.props.project //projects contains the needed data
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // this.logger.info("------ componentDidMount");
    if(this.props.originalIndex === this.props.currentIndex) {
      this.getProjectData();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevProps.time !== this.props.time
      && this.props.originalIndex === this.props.currentIndex) {
      this.getProjectData();
    }
  }

  render() {
    var homeService = new HomeService();
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <div className="projectContainer">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <div className='sweet-loading'>
                  <ClipLoader
                    sizeUnit={"px"}
                    size={100}
                    color={'#FFECA5'}
                    loading={this.state.isLoading} />
                </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="projectContainer">
            <div className="container-fluid">
             <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                  <ProjectHeaderComponent header={this.state.project}></ProjectHeaderComponent>
               {<ServiceStatusListComponent functionalities={ homeService.getProjectStatusById(this.props.id)} time={this.props.time} 
                  originalIndex = {this.props.originalIndex} currentIndex = {this.props.currentIndex}></ServiceStatusListComponent>}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  getProjectData() {
    this.setState({
      project: {},
      isLoading: false
    });
    var homeService = new HomeService();


    this.setState({
      isLoading:false,
      projectResponse: homeService.getProjectStatusById(this.props.id)
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Provide code for <ProjectComponent/>.

Comment: check in `render`, before `return`, provide code for `<Slider />` ;)

Comment: @AvinashMahlawat I've added the code. Xadm Slider is a Reactjs component, I did not write code for it

Comment: @xadm What do I have to check in render? I've tried printing the same as in constructor but it prints correctly

Comment: Edited with one more test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving

```
this.data.map(projectId => console.log("Call "));
```

to `render` helps when `this.data` can change in lifecycles. If hardcoded - no difference. If not `render` is a better place to check state/props right before returning view.

It's better to `console.log` something more meaningfull, too.

In this case it would help debugging because you're iterating over objects, not reaching real `projectId` property. The same error occurs within `render`. Instead of idetifier you're using refs to object - `key`ing fails allowing for `<ProjectComponent/>` duplicates.

There should be

```
this.data.map( project =>  
          <ProjectComponent key={project.projectId} project={project}
```

The `<ProjectComponent />` source was not needed - component can't duplicate itself. That's why its parents needs inspection, f.e. `<Slider />` (direct parent) and the 'main' component. If `<Slider />` was rendered once then only the second can be a source of error.

As we have `<ProjectComponent />` source, we see errors there:

- using `this.props.id` while no `id` prop passed;
- unnecessary creating `homeService` when condition can lead to render 'loading'

Comment: Hi, thank you, the problem was with key={project.projectId}. I passed only project. Thanks!